# GSON fromJson() hangs and silently crashes with graphics Path

Tags: android, gson

I need to serialize Path object and faced with weird impossibility. App just stops.

Let's place a simple test right in onCreate()

```
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import android.graphics.Path;

    ...

    Gson g=new Gson();
    Path p=new Path();
    p.addRect(0,0,100,100, Path.Direction.CCW);
    String s=g.toJson(p).toString(); 
    p = g.fromJson(s, Path.class); //(1)
```

run the app and wait ~5-15 sec. First it hangs, then will silently crash. If you comment the string (1), it will work. If you change (1)'s *Path.class* to *p.getClass()* or *new TypeToken<Path>(){}.getType()* - it will not help. So the reason is in **fromJson**.

I tried 4 devices with SDK from 17 to 25, and behavior is the same. What's wrong, how to store Path to JSON?

**p.s.** gradle uses com.google.code.gson:gson:2.+

**edit:** my assumption is infinite Path's loop, which is confusing GSON.

**edit2:** they say, it is impossible to serialize Path. I wrote my own implementation around Path with parallel List and it works fine

**edit3:** here is possible error and string asked in comments

> 08-13 19:33:40.380 883-1405/? E/NativeCrashListener: Exception dealing
>   with report
>                                                        android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EAGAIN (Try again)
>                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
>                                                            at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:165)
>                                                            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
>                                                            at android.system.Os.read(Os.java:350)
>                                                            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.consumeNativeCrashData(NativeCrashListener.java:240)
>                                                            at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener.run(NativeCrashListener.java:138)

.

> s={"isSimplePath":true,"mLastDirection":"CCW","mNativePath":-1221497024,"rects":{"mNativeRegion":-1222844744}}

Comment: what's in the exception? post it, also if possible post the value of `s`

Comment: @Yazan see edited question. Im not sure about exception but there is only one.

Comment: nothing in this exceptions tells it's by your app, it's from the OS and platform unless it's caused by your app, then it's something i don't know about !!, JSON looks simple i don't think it will cause such loop or recursive issue ?!

Comment: @Yazan true. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid your code here is right and exception comes from other place
This is my small test and the no crash happen
Why don't you separate this to have a try

[image: MyDemo]

Comment: interesting. But separate what?

Answer (score 0):

**Okay, the answer.** Official causes are: 1. it is impossible, 2. yes, it is infinite cycle.

> You should never serialize an object that is outside of your control
>   and which weren't explicitly designed for serialization. In this
>   example, the internals of Path are an implementation detail. The
>   correct way to serialize this would be to register a TypeAdapter for
>   the type and use its public API to decide what representation you want
>   in JSON.
>
> In Moshi, the spiritual successor to Gson, we actually forbid
>   serializing anything in the android.* package by default unless you
>   register a manual adapter to define the JSON format. Unfortunately
>   it's too late to change Gson to do the same.
>
> As to the actual cause here, your guess of a reference cycle in the
>   implementation details of Path is the cause.

https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1140